# Connect to DynamoDB in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to get my Alexa skill programmed in Node.js to make a query in my dynamodb table.

I have this in the header:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-west-1",
});

var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
```

And in one of my intends I call this:

```
var params = {
      TableName: 'TblName',
        Key:{
            "User": 'TestUser'
        }
        };
docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
if (err) {
    this.emit(':tell', 'A');
} else {
    this.emit(':tell', 'B');
}
});
```

Now I thought that this would either throw an error, return A or return B. But for some reason, I simply get no response at all. Is there any obvious thing I am doing wrong?

Edit: If I change the table name to a non-existing one, I still don't get an error message or an A output. It just executes the rest of the code.

Edit: I guess one problem is identical to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33942945/error-invalidparametertype-expected-params-itempid-to-be-a-structure-in-dyn). I will close as soon as I got it fully working.

Comment: This is an asynchronous operation. Are you returning this .get method from wherever you're calling it?

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: My main problem was that "this" was undefined in the callback function. Adding a "=>" passes the reference to this along. So the correct line is "docClient.get(params, (err, data) => {"