# DynamoDB DocumentClient.put returns DynamoDB.putItem error unexpectedly

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am using Dynamo DB and Node JS, and I am receiving errors with my put methods that don't make any sense.

It seems almost at random that I receive an error that the DocumentClient.put is expecting the object to match the DynamoDB.putItem method, producing this error (this is one example, but I receive an error for every field):

```
InvalidParameterType: Expected params.Item['startDateTime'] to be a structure","
```

Here is what my Object looks like:

```
payload: {
   TableName: TABLE, 
   Item: {
    gameId: 3534422,
    awayhome: 'ATLMIN',
    startDateTime: '2020-10-18T17:00:00Z',
    location: 'Minneapolis, Minnesota',
    stadium: 'U.S. Bank Stadium',
    sport: 'nfl',
    year: 2020,
    season: 'Regular',
    awayTeam: { 
        fullName: 'Atlanta Falcons',
        shortName: 'Falcons',
        code: 'ATL' 
    },
    homeTeam: {
      fullName: 'Minnesota Vikings',
      shortName: 'Vikings',
      code: 'MIN'
    },
    gameStatus: 'Unplayed' 
} 
}
```

Here's my put call to DynamoDB from Lambda:

```
db.put(payload, function(err,data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('update error: ', err);
        callback(err, null);
    }
    if (data) {
        console.log({ successfulUpdate: data });
    }
})
```

What's strange is that it happens seemingly without any clear indication why. I'll make a small change to my Lambda function, sometimes without changing the object or DynamoDB call at all, and will receive the error.

Comment: Do you modify payload in between so that it is the expected format: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#put-property?

Comment: This might help you who faced same issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33942945/error-invalidparametertype-expected-params-itempid-to-be-a-structure-in-dyn

Comment: Yes, I do include the Table Name and Item in my payload. I'm using the DocumentClient methods, which is the recommended path, and was the answer in that linked question.

Comment: did you used the documentClient constructor for creating the db instance instead of AWS.DynamoDB() ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html

Comment: Yes, I am creating a DocumentClient according to the documentation.

Comment: As I mentioned, the function works and then it doesn't, and I cannot really understand why, especially when I don't make any changes to the function or the object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand how this fixed the issue, but what I ultimately did was this.

I was creating the payload in a different method and using that output directly.

Instead, I reassembled it like so:

```
const { gameId,
    awayhome,
    status,
    startDateTime,
    location,
    stadium,
    sport,
    year,
    season,
    homeTeam,
    awayTeam
} = payload.Item

    payload.Item = {
        gameId,
        awayhome,
        status,
        startDateTime,
        location,
        stadium,
        sport,
        year,
        season,
        homeTeam: {...homeTeam},
        awayTeam: {...awayTeam},
        odds: {
            spread: odds.spread,
            total: odds.total,
            history: odds.history,
            prices: odds.prices
        }
    }
```

I added back pieces of the payload until it worked. I'm guessing that there may have been some malformed properties or something.